# WIC Direct2D CreateBitmapFromMemory: limitations on width and height?

Tags: c++, direct2d, wic

CreateBitmapFromMemory executes successfully when **_nWidth** is **equal to or less than 644.**
If the value exceeds this value, the HRESULT value is -2003292276

Do limits exist on the width and height?

```
#include <d2d1.h>
#include <d2d1helper.h>

#include <wincodecsdk.h> // Use this for WIC Direct2D functions


void test() 
{
    IWICImagingFactory     *m_pIWICFactory;   
    ID2D1Factory           *m_pD2DFactory;
    IWICBitmap             *m_pEmbeddedBitmap;
    ID2D1Bitmap            *m_pD2DBitmap;

    unsigned char *pImageBuffer = new unsigned char[1024*1024];

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    int _nHeight = 300;
    int _nWidth =  644;
```

If nWidth exceeds 644, CreateBitmapFromMemory returns an Error.

```
    //_nWidth =  648;


    if (m_pIWICFactory == 0 )
    {
        hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);

        // Create WIC factory
        hr = CoCreateInstance(
            CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
            NULL,
            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
            IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pIWICFactory)
            );

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Create D2D factory
            hr = D2D1CreateFactory( D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &m_pD2DFactory );
        }
    }

     hr = m_pIWICFactory->CreateBitmapFromMemory(
        _nHeight,   // height
        _nWidth,  // width
        GUID_WICPixelFormat24bppRGB, // pixel format of the NEW bitmap
        _nWidth*3,  // calculated from width and bpp information
        1024*1024, // height x width
        pImageBuffer, // name of the .c array
        &m_pEmbeddedBitmap  // pointer to pointer to whatever an IWICBitmap is.
        ); 

    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        char *buffer = "Error in CreateBitmapFromMemory\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use GetLastError to get the exact error information

Comment: When CreateBitmapFromMemory returns, hr =  -2003292276, GetLastError() returns 0, converted to HEX:  0x88982F8C, The Direct2D Error Codes start with 0x889...., http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370979(v=vs.85).aspx, but this error is not listed there.

Comment: The error is E_INVALIDARG, but that's not help, we don't know how MS check the arguments, but there is a work around, you can set bitsPerPixel to 32 to make your code work.

Comment: The bitsPerPixel is set in the parameter of the CreateBitmapFromMemory( ,,GUID_WICPixelFormat24bppRGB,...), is there somewhere else it must be specified?

Comment: You calculate stride = _nWidth * 3, since 24 / 8 = 3, try using 32bit color, that's _nWidth * (32 / 8) = _nWidth * 4.

Answer (score 3):

Error code is [0x88982F8C `WINCODEC_ERR_INSUFFICIENTBUFFER`](http://alax.info/blog/1383) and the reason is now obvious?

The [first parameter is width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and the second is height. You have them in wrong order. All in all you provide incorrect arguments resulting in bad buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you passed in the correct pixelFormat for function CreateBitmapFromMemory? you hard code it to GUID_WICPixelFormat24bppRGB, I think this is the root cause, you should make sure this format same as the format with the source bitmap which you are copy the data from. try use the GetPixelFormat function to get the correct format instead of hard code.

Answer (score 0):

There is an upper limit on the dimensions of images on the GPU.

Call GetMaximumBitmapSize on the render target.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(GetMaximumBitmapSize);k(DevLang-C%2B%2B);k(TargetOS-Windows)&rd=true

What you get back is the max pixels of either vertical or horiz.
For larger images you'd have to load them into a software render target such as a bitmap render target and then render what you want from that.